# My Elantech touchpad doesn't feel as good as it does in windows 10

Tags: gnome, touchpad, 17.04, asus

I have an Asus Zenbook UX550V, running Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 and Windows 10.

I have an Elantech touchpad and it works ridiculously well in Windows 10. It is incredibly precise, down to the pixel.

The same, however, cannot be said in Ubuntu Gnome. It works in every regard except, tapping isn't quite as sensitive and my biggest issue is that when making small movements, it just doesn't as well as it does in Windows 10.

For example, in Windows 10 if I make really tiny circles, the cursor will, expectedly, make tiny circles. In Ubuntu however, it *might* skip a couple dozen pixels in one direction, then another, then another, etc. This makes highlighting text, zoning in on guis, moving windows around, and other tasks a real pain. Any help on making it perform like it does in Windows 10 would be fantastic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I'm not too late.

Have you checked `synclient` on this?

if you haven't install that (`sudo apt install synclient`) and show the output.

Mine is something like this.

```
> synclient 
Parameter settings:
LeftEdge                = 129
RightEdge               = 3105
TopEdge                 = 126
BottomEdge              = 2211
FingerLow               = 1
FingerHigh              = 1
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 175
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = -79
HorizScrollDelta        = -79
VertEdgeScroll          = 1
HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.0501253
TouchpadOff             = 0
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 2
RBCornerButton          = 3
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 1
TapButton2              = 3
TapButton3              = 2
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 3
ClickFinger3            = 0
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 1
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 35
CoastingFriction        = 40
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
ResolutionDetect        = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 0
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 19
VertHysteresis          = 19
ClickPad                = 1
RightButtonAreaLeft     = 1617
RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
RightButtonAreaTop      = 1916
RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

Usually by editing the `CoastingSpeed` and `CoastingFriction` you can find the sweet spot. I set mine up to 35 and 40 using:

```
synclient CoastingSpeed=35
synclient CoastingFriction=40
```

Save that on a text file and rename it as startup.sh and run it on every startup using Startup Applications.

synclient has lot of other cool options too, you should check it out like three finger tap to be recognized as a middle click, helps pasting stuff and opening new tabs. [Middle Click](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-middleclick.html)

Comment: If you have settings that are only temporary, but you would like them to apply for each login, add them to the bottom of your `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` files, as a more portable and lower overhead option to using Startup Applications and a separate file just for those settings.

Comment: @prab4th Thank you so much! Actually, changing both `HorizHysteresis` and `VertHysteresis` to 0 is what fixed it for me, and it is perfect now!

The only issue is that after installing `synclient`, my palm detection has gone to hell. I tried to tinker with `PalmMinWidth` and `PalmMinZ`, but I can't quite get it right by trial and error. Are there better methods to figuring this out besides trial and error?

Comment: Set `PalmDetect = 1` ?